# UserForm in Excel 2013 Discount Textbox

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a problem because I want to compute a discount for my 2 **`textbox`** that will display on 3rd **`textbox`**.

```
 1. txtPrice
 2. txtDiscount
 3. txtTotal
```

but I don't know how to put like `txtPrice * .txtDiscount` (eg 100 * .10) for computing for the discount.

I'm using this code :

```
Private Sub txtDiscount_Change()

    If txtPrice.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If txtDiscount.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    txtTotal.Value = CDbl(txtPrice.Value) * CDbl(txtDiscount.Value)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a few changes on this code and it solves my problem.

Hope this will help anyone in the future.

```
Private Sub txtDiscount_Change()

If txtPrice.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
If txtDiscount.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
txtTotal.Value = (CDbl(txtPrice.Value)) - (CDbl(txtPrice.Value) * CDbl(txtDiscount.Value))
```

End Sub